# Getting first and last values from contiguous ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, gaps-and-islands

I want to get the first `enter_date` and the last `leave_date` for contiguous `enter_day` and `leave_day` values for each `id`. Given this example data:

```
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| id  | enter_date | leave_date | enter_day | leave_day |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
| 111 | 2016-07-29 | 2016-12-01 |         1 |        75 |
| 111 | 2016-12-02 | 2017-01-13 |        76 |        95 |
| 111 | 2017-01-17 | 2017-06-02 |        96 |       181 |
| 222 | 2016-07-29 | 2016-12-02 |         1 |        76 |
| 222 | 2017-01-30 | 2017-06-02 |       105 |       181 |
| 333 | 2016-08-01 | 2017-06-02 |         1 |       180 |
+-----+------------+------------+-----------+-----------+
```

I want the following result:

```
+-----+------------+------------+
| id  | enter_date | leave_date |
+-----+------------+------------+
| 111 | 2016-07-29 | 2017-06-02 |
| 222 | 2016-07-29 | 2016-12-02 |
| 222 | 2017-01-30 | 2017-06-02 |
| 333 | 2016-08-01 | 2017-06-02 |
+-----+------------+------------+
```

I want one record for ID 111 because there are no gaps between any `enter_day` and the previous `leave_day`.

I want both records for ID 222 because there is a gap (days 75 through 104).

**EDIT:** What I have so far, which isn't giving me the correct `leave_date` for ID 111:

```
with cte as (
    select a.id, a.enter_date, a.leave_date, b.enter_date next_ed, b.leave_date next_ld
    from #tbl a
    join #tbl b on b.id = a.id and b.enter_day = a.leave_day + 1
)
select id, min(enter_date) enter_date, max(leave_date) leave_date
from cte
group by id
union
select a.id, a.enter_date, a.leave_date
from #tbl a
left join #tbl b on b.id = a.id and b.enter_day = a.leave_day + 1
left join cte c on c.id = a.id and c.next_ed = a.enter_date and c.next_ld = a.leave_date
where b.id is null and c.id is null
order by 1,3
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? This isn't a code writing service.

Comment: Search for gaps and islands. This is a classic example of this type of query.

Comment: I've been looking at gaps-and-islands examples all morning and all the ones I've found are for gaps in a single column, or gaps in dates (which I don't want).

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of Gaps-and-Islands for ranges.

I used an ad-hoc tally table, but an actual number/tally would do the trick as well.

If you just run the inner query, you will see very quickly how your sample data of 6 rows explodes into 514 rows.  Then is is a small matter of applying the grouped aggregation to get the final results.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([id] int,[enter_date] date,[leave_date] date,[enter_day] int,[leave_day] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 (111,'2016-07-29','2016-12-01',1,75)
,(111,'2016-12-02','2017-01-13',76,95)
,(111,'2017-01-17','2017-06-02',96,181)
,(222,'2016-07-29','2016-12-02',1,76)
,(222,'2017-01-30','2017-06-02',105,181)
,(333,'2016-08-01','2017-06-02',1,180)

Select ID
      ,[enter_date] = min([enter_date])
      ,[leave_date] = max([leave_date])
 From (
        Select *
              ,Grp = N - Row_Number() over (Partition By ID Order by N)
         From @YourTable A
         Join (
                  Select Top (Select max([leave_day]-[enter_day])+1 From @YourTable)
                         N=-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null))
                  From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
              ) B on B.N between [enter_day] and [leave_day]
      ) A 
 Group By [ID],Grp
 Order By [ID],min([enter_date])
```

Returns

```
ID  enter_date  leave_date
111 2016-07-29  2017-06-02
222 2016-07-29  2016-12-02
222 2017-01-30  2017-06-02
333 2016-08-01  2017-06-02
```

Comment: Thanks, John. That does work, but my table has ~36,000 rows and your solution ran for a minute before I cancelled the query. I should note that my "table" is actually the results of another CTE. I've also tried putting those results in a temp table but the solution is still slow. Any suggestions?

Comment: @DakotaPaul Took your sample and expanded the scope to 30,000 and returned results in 12 seconds on my laptop.  Not fabulous, but not horrible.   One tweak is to make the join a little more efficient is rather than Select Top 1000 .... make it Select Top (Select max([leave_day]-[enter_day])+1 From @YourTable) ...